# Making a clickable text in terminal for running commands

Tags: terminal

How can I make a clickable text *(f.e.: `[Create File]`)* in a terminal, that runs a command *(f.e.: `[touch new_file.txt]`)*?

Comment: I'm confused because of your `w3m` tag. Do you want to make `w3m` execute a shell command when clicking a link? Or do you want to create a link in a terminal that will execute a command, independently of `w3m`? If the latter, which terminal are you using?

Comment: I want to create a link that will execute a command, independently of w3m. Im using LXTerm, but it would be good to have it working everywhere. I've seen this feature in W3M and I forgot to remove the tag, after editing my question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dialog`, which runs in terminal and displays clickable buttons:

```
if dialog --yes-label 'Yes Button' --no-label 'No button' \
--yesno 'Create new file?' 10 100; then 
    touch new_file.txt
fi
clear
```

The file will only be created if the *yes* button is chosen. `clear` is optional and cleans the screen after a button was pressed.

There are many more box options besides `--yesno`, as you can find in `man dialog`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a terminal-based application, e.g. using ncurses, that paints stuff on the screen and listens for mouse events. Then it can display the text "Create File", and if you click on that, this application – as long as it's running – can launch the "touch" command or whatever you want.

Terminals luckily don't natively support the "feature" you're looking for, this would have critical security and privacy implications if malicious terminal-based applications (even remote ones, e.g. after you ssh to a compromised site) could print something that upon clicking executes arbitrary commands locally (e.g. purge your files, or upload them to the attacker).